Как тестировала АПИ? Отправляла тот же джейсон, что с фронта?
Как тестировала АПИ? Отправляла тот же джейсон, что с фронта? Если да, то для чего, если нет, то как проходило тестирование?
Интересно как бы ответили на этот вопрос

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Тестирование, это проверка правильности работы кода при любых значениях входящих параметров. У API есть точка обращения и список передаваемых в него параметров, которые могут меняться, а так же возвращаемые значения.
Все возможные значения в тестах не прогоняют. Только некоторый ключевой набор сценариев, возможных в системе, и сравнивают корректность ответов/данных на запросы. Данные обычно берут исходя из различных соображений:

правильный набор данных:

с обычными данными
с граничными значениями
с ключевыми значениями параметров, которые могут сильно влиять на результат
по сценарию, которые наиболее часто пользователь проходит в системе
и т.д


неправильный набор данных, который должен давать сообщение об ошибке:

неполный набор данных
полностью некорректные значения
значения, выходящие за диапазон
значения, которые противоречат друг другу
и т.д



Поэтому нет, просто взять JSON с фронта и его отправить, это не тестирование, это просто проверка доступности API на работоспособность в одном примере. Тестирование, это составить наборы данных и прогнать их, проверив корректность ответов и самих данных в системе.
